# ¿Porque al reenviar un correo de gmail a outlook, este pierde algunos estilos?

Tags: css, email, gmail, outlook

Estoy realizando una creación de emails, cuando se envía el correo por primera vez a cualquier clientes, ya sea [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail), [outlook](/questions/tagged/outlook), etc... se ve genial.

El problema viene cuando se reenvía de [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail) hacia [outlook](/questions/tagged/outlook), pierde algunos estilos y provoca que algunas imágenes se dupliquen.

Para condicionar el renderizado de las imagenes utilizo condiciones propias de [outlook](/questions/tagged/outlook) como lo es:

```html
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    
//content
    
<!--<![endif]-->
```

¿Puede que estas se pierdan cuando se reenvía de [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail) hacía [outlook](/questions/tagged/outlook)? Porque de [outlook](/questions/tagged/outlook) hacia [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail) todo se ve genial.